# Using COM object from C++ that in C#.NET returns object []

Tags: c#, c++, com, variant

I have a COM object that I'm trying to use from C++ (not .NET), and all of the example programs and manual are written assuming the use of C#.NET or VB.NET. COM is new to me so I'm a bit overwhelmed. I'm using #import on the TLB but am struggling to deal with the variants that are used as parameters. I have one particular method, that according to the docs and the example programs in C#.NET, is supposed to return an object[]. Then I'm supposed to cast the first entry in this array to a ControlEvent which then tells me what to do with the rest of the objects in the array. The C#.NET example looks like:

```
object [] objEvent = (object []) Ctl.GetEvent();
ControlEvent ev = (ControlEvent) objEvent[0];
```

In my case, GetEvent is returning me a _variant_t and I need to know how to convert this to an object[] so that I can further process. Its not clear to me even how I express 'object' in C++. I see _variant_t documentation showing me a million things I can convert the variant to, but none of them seem to be converting to anything I can use. I'm hoping for some assistance converting the above C#.NET code to Visual C++

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you look at the `vt` member of the variant to see what type of thing it actually is. In this case I would expect it to be an array, so you would expect that the vartype would be some variation on VT_ARRAY (usually it is bitwise OR'ed with the type of the members). Then, you get the `parray` member which contains the `SAFEARRAY` instance that actually holds the array, and use the normal safe array functions to get the data out of the array.

Comment: Thanks, I think you've set me on the right track. The vt is VT_ARRAY || VT_VARIANT, I get back from the API call a SafeArray w/ two elements, each of which is a VT_I4. However lVal for both is zero, so I'm still stuck on how I'm supposed to turn these VT_I4's into pointers to objects

Comment: Can you show the code that you've used to retrieve `SAFEARRAY` elements and got `VT_I4`?

Comment: _variant_t v = m_pCtl->getNextEvent()
printf ("Variant Type is %x\n", v.vt);  [[Prints 0x200c]]
_variant_t item
LONG idx=0
HRESULT hr = SafeArrayGetElement(v.parray,&idx,&item)
if (hr==S_OK)
  printf ("Element Type is: %d\n",item.vt);  [[prints 3]]

Comment: If the return values were pointers to objects, the type would be VT_DISPATCH or VT_UNKNOWN - since it is VT_I4, the method is returning some kind of integer value.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this, but from reading the documentation for the `_variant_t` class (and the comments below which corrected my original post), I think you should read the `vt` field of the  `_variant_t` instance (actually the `VARTYPE vt` field of the `VARIANT` instance: the `_variant_t` instance directly derives from `VARIANT`) to see what type of thing it contains, as described in the reference documentation for the `VARIANT` struct. One you know what type of thing is contained in the variant, use the corresponding type-specific operator to read it.

You'll be in for some hurt if you try to use COM without understanding it (and you may want a book which describes that); you may well need to know about the `IUnknown` interface and the `AddRef` method, for example.

Comment: You do not detach the VARIANT instance from the _variant_t wrapper, unless you need to pass it whole to some external interface. The _variant_t is a smart wrapper class that can be treated more or less as the underlying instance

Comment: How else (without detaching the VARIANT) do you read the VARIANT's vt field value? I don't see in the documentation a _variant_t method to return the VARTYPE.

Comment: You do instance.vt - the _variant_t instance directly derives from VARIANT